# Seeking rayon (district) level administrative boundaries for North Caucasus Federal District (Russia)

Tags: data-request, geospatial, county, russia, district

I am doing a research project in which I need *accurate* **rayon (district) level administrative boundaries for the North Caucasus Federal District of Russia** (shapefile or geodatabase). Among other sites I have checked HDX, Natural Earth, DIVA-GIS, and GADM.

HDX unfortunately does not have admin boundaries for Russia. Natural Earth has admin boundaries, but they do not have subdivisions for Russia. The DIVA-GIS files are based on GADM. Other gis.stackexchange posts on Russian admin boundaries have suggested GADM or DIVA-GIS as a source (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220160/map-of-russias-administrative-divisions) or specific republic map sources.

So I ended up using GADM without issues until now. However, when attempting to match 2010 census data to rayons I found that there are missing some rayons and have a few major cities on the wrong side of borders.

For example, their map of the subdivisions of Karachay-Cherkess Republic is missing 2 rayons (Abazinsky and Nogaysky) which were created in 2006 and 2007 respectively.
Republic of Ingushetia had Dzheyrakhsky rayon missing which was created all the way back in 1993.
Another example: They have the Chechnen Republic with 12 rayon, but it should have 3 more: https://gadm.org/maps/RUS/chechnya_2.html

Does anyone know of a more *accurate* source for rayon level admin boundaries for the 7 Federal Subjects that make up the North Caucasus Federal District? Or for Russia in general?